# Creating common class in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, oop

I have one html page with some div and table inside div. Getting data by using `XHTMLREQUEST`. How can I make this to wrapper class so I can use it whenever I want in project with some id.

I can create div with id and use that particularturl for the loading data. How can I make it common so I can use it anywhere.

My htmlcode:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 30%;
  height : 30%;
  overflow-y:auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: none;
  margin-top:-12px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
  width : 10%;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  order-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#myInput:focus + #myTable{
  display: block;
}

#myTable:hover{
 display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header"></tr> 
  <tr><td>Germany</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Sweden</td></tr>
  <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Germany</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Canada</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Italy</td></tr>
  <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
  <tr><td>France</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr:not(.header)').forEach(function(_tr){
    _tr.addEventListener('click',function(){
              document.getElementById('myInput').value += " "+  this.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent;
    });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is how I am loading the data.

```
function foo(callback) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', "data.json",true);
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && httpRequest.status === 200) {
            // trigger your callback function
            callback(httpRequest.responseText);
        }
    };
    httpRequest.send();
}

foo(function(data) {
    var jsonc = JSON.parse(data);
    var new_opt="";
    for(i=0;i<jsonc.length;i++)
    {
        new_opt+='<option value="'+jsonc[i]['VALUE']+'">'+jsonc[i]['VALUE']+'</option>';
    }
    document.getElementById('choose').innerHTML =new_opt;
});
```

I know this code I can use only for this place. But I want same idea for another div also. I just wann pass some id and create the same div which I using here. 
Can anybody help me in Javascript class which should be generic class.

Comment: Could you not use classes instead of IDs?

Comment: I wanted to make it generic. A plane JS code. In that I can create html and other stuff.

Comment: You'd either need a selector (data attr, class, whatever) or you could add an onclick="foo"